How to open 'Computer Management' using a button in windows forms in visual basic?
I created a form in visual basic where I placed a button intended to open "Computer Management" when clicked on.
In the button code portion, I used 'process.start("compmgmt.msc") but it did not work. Does anyone know what is the proper command?

have you tried basic troubleshooting like process.start("calc.exe") did that open the windows calculator?
programmign questions are for stackoverflow.com but this question is very poorly researched.

.msc files are not executables. In fact, they are Microsoft Management Console definition files that get loaded by mmc.exe.
try running it like process.start("mmc.exe", "compmgmt.msc") see here for doc.

Thank you SO VERY much!! It worked like a charm :)
